# node.js and typescript definition file for async.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, typescript

I am trying to create the following in async.d.ts:

```
interface AsyncIteratorCallback {
    (err?: string): void;
}
interface AsyncEachIterator<T>{ (item: T, callback: AsyncIteratorCallback): void;}

declare module "async" {


    // Collections
    function each<T>(arr: T[], iterator: AsyncEachIterator<T>, callback: AsyncIteratorCallback): void;
}
```

but i am not allowed to make the err? optional in the AsyncIteratorCallback?

when i use it:

```
async.each([],(item,cb) => {},(err) => {});
```

i get `Call signatures of types '(err: string) => void' and '"async".AsyncIteratorCallback' are incompatible:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I tried this code in Visual Studio 2012

```
interface test {
    (err:string):void
}

var a = (err: string) => { };
var b = (param: test) => { };
b(a);
```

It works. Apparently the function a implements the interface test.
Then I changed this code to:

```
interface test {
    (err?:string):void
}

var a = (err: string) => { }; 
var b = (param: test) => { };
b(a);  // error, incompatible call signatures
```

Now the function doesn't implement the interface. The solution is to add an ? to the function parameter, too. This code works again:

```
interface test {
    (err?:string):void
}

var a = (err?: string) => { }; 
var b = (param: test) => { };
b(a);  // error, incompatible call signatures
```

Finally I tried the following:

```
interface test {
    (err:string):void
}

var a = (err: string) => { };
var b = (param: test) => { };
b({ method:a });  // error, no overload of call
```

I had already wondered about the interface definition since I had never seen an interface with a method without name. It seems that an object can't implement this interface. Even this code doesn't work:

```
b({ call: a });
```

**Solution**

You should just add the ? to your lambda. `(err?)=>{}`

Comment: its not an empty object, its a lambda. function ano(item,cb) { }.

Comment: you're right, I played with VisualStudio and updated my answer